# ¿Como presentar un valor de una variable local en una caja de texto de un formulario HTML con código PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo realizada una función sobre una suma de multas; en cada registro de una nueva multa aumenta el valor en una variable local llamada $total, todo eso realiza la función al presionar el botón Calcular

¿ Como puedo hacer que ese valor almacenado en $total se presente en una caja de texto también debido a que intente:

```
... input type ="submit" value ="..echo $total; ?>"
```

y no me funciona
(esta con puntitos porque no puedo como me aparezca todo )

Agradezco alguna sugerencia

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero leer [ask], de paso también el [tour] pues tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato; es decir eso es lo que intentas lograr, pero nos muestras que has intentado o investigado?

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Creo entender que te refieres a algo así:

```
<?php $total=16; ?>

<form>
    <input type="text" value="<?=$total?>">
</form>
```